# How to call overloaded SOAP method with PHP SoapClient?

Tags: php, soap, confluence

[Confluence soap api](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Remote+API+Specification) defines two methods with the same name but different parameters:

- Page getPage(String token, long pageId) - returns a single Page (according to the documentation the second parameter is String, but in WSDL it is long)
- Page getPage(String token, String spaceKey, String pageTitle) - returns a single Page

I would need to call the method with two parameters using PHP SoapClient. In WSDL mode SoapClient insists on using the three-parameter one. In non-WSDL mode I managed to make a call with two parameters, but I cannot make the type of the second parameter to be long. How can I get the SoapClient to call getPage with two parameters with the correct types?

Here's what I've done so far:

Using SoapClient in WSDL mode...

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient("http://xxx/confluence/rpc/soap-axis/confluenceservice-v1?wsdl", array("trace" => TRUE));
$token = $soapClient->login(CONFLUENCE_USERNAME, CONFLUENCE_PASSWORD);
$page = $soapClient->getPage($token, $confluence_article_id);
```

...produces a request for the three-parameter method (only body shown)...

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:getPage><in0 xsi:type="xsd:string">dkjLIx00Ap</in0><in1 xsi:type="xsd:string">24445207</in1><in2 xsi:nil="true"/></ns1:getPage></SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

...which causes fault:

```
<faultstring>com.atlassian.confluence.rpc.RemoteException: You're not allowed to view that page, or it does not exist.</faultstring>
```

The page with that ID does exist and I am allowed to see it, which I can confirm by making the correct kind of request with SoapUI.

Using SoapClient is non-WSDL mode...

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient(null, array(
    "location" => "http://xxx/confluence/rpc/soap-axis/confluenceservice-v1",
    "uri" => "http://soap.rpc.confluence.atlassian.com",
    "trace" => TRUE));
$token = $soapClient->login(CONFLUENCE_USERNAME, CONFLUENCE_PASSWORD);
$page = $soapClient->getPage($token, $confluence_article_id);
```

...produces a request for the two-parameter method with incorrect type for the second parameter. When $confluence_article_id is string, the request is...

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:getPage><param0 xsi:type="xsd:string">8Or94ZLqe7</param0><param1 xsi:type="xsd:string">24445207</param1></ns1:getPage></SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

...which returns the same fault as above:

```
<faultstring>com.atlassian.confluence.rpc.RemoteException: You're not allowed to view that page, or it does not exist.</faultstring>
```

When $confluence_article_id is integer, the request is...

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:getPage><param0 xsi:type="xsd:string">y0kF4z0m9L</param0><param1 xsi:type="xsd:int">24445207</param1></ns1:getPage></SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

...which returns a different kind of fault:

```
<faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXException: Bad types (int -> class java.lang.String)</faultstring>
```

If I take the request, change int to long and try it with SoapUI, it works just fine.

I have also tried to call it using __soapCall, but the results are similar:

```
$page = $soapClient -> __soapCall('getPage', array('in0'=>$token,'in1'=>$confluence_article_id));
```

There is a related PHP [bug report](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=31248) and [another one](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43868), and [discussion on Atlassian forums](http://forums.atlassian.com/message.jspa?messageID=257285096), but none of them helped me.

So far the best suggestion has been to tweak the WSDL by removing the other getPage definition and saving it locally somewhere.

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51099774/6783224

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly you can call the function using an associative array instead ex:

```
//Page getPage(String token, String spaceKey, String pageTitle)
$soapClient->getPage(array("token" => $token,"spaceKey" => $spaceKey,"pageTitle" => $pageTitle));
```

Not tested, standard warnings apply

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think I tried that too without success (I'm not involved with that project any more so I cannot verify). I ended up using a tweaked version of WSDL where I had removed the other getPage definition. Accepting your answer anyway :)