# Consuming overloaded web service with php

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, overloading

I recently ran into a problem. I had to consume a webservice developed in dotnet from PHP. For that I used soap client. But now, one of the method in that webservice is overloaded and I can't seem to access it.

So my question is whether is it possible to access overloaded method using the soap client approach? If yes, could someone please lead me to the right direction!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jarnoan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109351/jarnoan) asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086542/how-to-call-overloaded-soap-method-with-php-soapclient) in 2010 but doesn't appear to have found it possible and in the end took the approach of rewriting the web service.

There is [an open PHP bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=31248) from 2005 which states that, for overloaded methods, only the top-most parameter set from the WSDL can be accessed. In 2013 the package maintainer reported it is "not going to be fixed". Is it possible for you to edit the .NET web service? :$

Comment: I thought so, thanks for the prompt reply. I will look around to see if the web service can be modified.